# Error while using pip3 to install paramiko on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, python3

```
$ pip3 install paramiko
Collecting paramiko
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/ae/94e70d49044ccc234bfdba20114fa947d7ba6eb68a2e452d89b920e62227/paramiko-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (193kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 162kB/s 
Collecting pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/ab/2ac6dea8489fa713e2b4c6c5b549cc962dd4a842b5998d9e80cf8440b7cd/PyNaCl-1.3.0.tar.gz (3.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.4MB 82kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
     Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
        extra_postargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
        spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
        _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 159, in _spawn_posix
        % (cmd, exit_status))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 161, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 147, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 23, in run
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 109, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 49, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 338, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 447, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 472, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 174, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 532, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
    raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-uo69dufp/cffi-1.11.5/setup.py", line 240, in <module>
    "build_clib": build_clib,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1087, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
    raise
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 243, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 273, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 242, in runner
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 46, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-uo69dufp/cffi-1.11.5/setup.py", line 240, in <module>
    "build_clib": build_clib,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-8l_5j1ha/pynacl/setup.py", line 255, in <module>
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 663, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 693, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 873, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1089, in run_setup
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Just install `python-paramiko` or `python3-paramiko` from the Trusty repositories with `apt-get install` rather than attempting to build it manually with pip.  Unless there's a specific reason you need newer paramiko?

Comment: Thanks a million!!! That worked out all right.